# How can I listen the event emitted from smart contract in web3 js?

Tags: reactjs, smartcontracts, web3js

I am now building NFT staking website and I have an issue.

I have built smart contract and made it to emit the event.
But in frontend, I cannot listen the event emitted properly. So I force listen to the event with hard coding.
The code is following.

```
var stakeTokenEvent = stakeToken.events.Staked();

let event = await stakeTokenEvent.on({}, function (error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    return result;
  } else {
    dispatch(spinner_show());
  }
});
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  if (event) {
    resolve("success");
  } else {
    reject("error");
  }
}).then(
  (success) => {
    dispatch(ghsp_connect());
  },
  (error) => {}
);
```

Are there any easy method or proper way to listen to the event emitted?

Answer (score 1):

from web3 doc([myContract.events.NameOfYourEvent()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events))

It's simple example:

```
    myContract.events.MyEvent([filter options])
      .on("connected", function(subscriptionId){ console.log(subscriptionId);})
      .on('data', function(event){ console.log(event);})
```